# how to get(webscrape) whatsapp stickers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

i have successfully made a program to see whatsapp deleted messages
algorithm is i get(webscrape all text messages from senders chat and put in a list and when sender deletes that text program sends that message which was deleted by sender but was there in our list

but problem is this only works with text messages
how to webscrape (get a whatsapp sticker from chat and saved in our pc)?
i tried finding stickers element and saving in different formats but it dosnt work
it gives Attribute error: webelement does not have attribute png,jpg etc

```
sticker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3rlNI TC9NX _2Q_wE _2DGdv']//canvas[@class='_1guNH']")
sticker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3rlNI TC9NX _2Q_wE _2DGdv']//canvas[@class='_1guNH']").png
sticker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3rlNI TC9NX _2Q_wE
```

_2DGdv']//canvas[@class='_1guNH']").jpg

can anyone help me?

Comment: i have done it in python selenium

Comment: plz help me anyone

Comment: <span class="_3cs02"><img class="_1guNH" draggable="false" src="blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/e599d083-513c-4682-9b11-25bccef4a99b" alt="Sticker with: ☕ "></span>

Comment: this is html of sticker

Comment: i found that stickers of whatsapp are in .webp extension but that also dont work

Comment: blob:web.whatsapp.com/e599d083-513c-4682-9b11-25bccef4a99b                                                      if you paste this browser then you will find that sticker but it sometimes dosnt show in browser but then also how to download that sticker in our pc